# jQuery toggle path navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to code a path navigation with jQuery.

This is how it looks at the moment:

```js
$("#one_link").click(function() {
  $("#categories").css("display", "block");
  $("#text_three").css("display", "none");
  $("#cats_text").css("display", "none");
  $("#text_two").css("display", "none");
});

$("#cats_link").click(function() {
  $("#cats_text").css("display", "block");
  $("#text_two").css("display", "none");
  $("#text_three").css("display", "none");
});

$("#two_link").click(function() {
  $("#text_two").css("display", "block");
  $("#categories").css("display", "none");
  $("#cats_text").css("display", "none");
  $("#text_three").css("display", "none");
});

$("#three_link").click(function() {
  $("#text_three").css("display", "block");
  $("#categories").css("display", "none");
  $("#cats_text").css("display", "none");
  $("#text_two").css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
* {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  font-family: Arial;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.column {
  border-right: 1px solid;
}

.column_content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column {
  display: none;
}

.column:first-child {
  display: block;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">

  <div class="column">
    <div class="column_content">
      <ul>
        <li id="one_link">One</li>
        <li id="two_link">Two</li>
        <li id="three_link">Three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="categories" class="column">
    <div class="column_content">
      <ul>
        <li id="cats_link">Cats</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column" id="cats_text">
    <div class="column_content">
      <p>The cat (Felis catus) is a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal. It is the only domesticated species in the family Felidae and is often referred to as the domestic cat to distinguish it from the wild members of the family.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column" id="text_two">
    <div class="column_content">
      <p>2 (two) is a number, numeral, and glyph. It is the natural number following 1 and preceding 3. It is the smallest and only even prime number. Because it forms the basis of a duality, it has religious and spiritual significance in many cultures.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column" id="text_three">
    <div class="column_content">
      <p>3 (three) is a number, numeral, and glyph. It is the natural number following 2 and preceding 4, and is the smallest odd prime number. It has religious or cultural significance in many societies.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

What I need is a toggle function for the links. For example, if you click one link a second time, the content should be hidden. Taking ».toggle« instead of ».click« doesn't work. And in general: Is there an easier way to code this? Or do I have to link it so detailed together as I did?

Would be very grateful for any help! <3

Comment: Use `toggle()`. And `show()` and `hide()` instead of `css()`. https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, unfortunately, this doesn't work at all: https://jsfiddle.net/e7fj3qdk/

Comment: Well, you're calling `toggle()` on each link, effectively hiding them as soon as the code runs. Read the documentation. `toggle()`... toggles the visibility of the element. You should use it with the element you're... toggling, and `hide()` for the other ones.

Comment: @Gabriel Aahhhh nice!!!! It works. But: How is it possible to avoid this weird toggle animation? »... .toggle( "slow", function() { ...« – If I write »0« instead of »slow«, nothing changes.

Comment: Yes, just call `toggle()` without any arguments.

Comment: @Gabriel: Then it's the same, still with animation: https://jsfiddle.net/dqbewu0p/1/

Comment: Without arguments, not even `function(){}`.

Comment: @Gabriel Ah cool, thanks! <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a data-target and commom class to the links:

```
<li class="tablink" id="two_link" data-target="text_two">Two</li>
```

A commom class to the texts:

```
<div class="column tabtext" id="text_two">
```

Make this hidden by default, and add a `visible` class:

```
.tabtext {
  opacity: 0;
  transition 0.2s;
}
.tabtext.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And to show/hide:

```
$("body").on("click", ".tablink", function(ev) {
  var target = $("#" + this.dataset.target);
  var show = !target.hasClass("visible"); // Only show if wasn't visible
  $(".tabtext.visible").removeClass("visible"); // Hide visible
  if (show) target.addClass("visible"); // Show the selected
});
```

```js
$("body").on("click", ".tablink", function(e) {
  var target = $("#" + this.dataset.target);
  var show = !target.hasClass("visible");
  $(".tabtext.visible").removeClass("visible");
  $(".tabtext2.visible").removeClass("visible"); // Hide 2nd level as well
  if (show) target.addClass("visible");
});

$("body").on("click", ".tablink2", function(ev) {
  var target = $("#" + this.dataset.target);
  var show = !target.hasClass("visible");
  $(".tabtext2.visible").removeClass("visible");
  if (show) target.addClass("visible");
});
```

```css
.tabtext,
.tabtext2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

* {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  font-family: Arial;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.column {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  visibility: visible;
}

.column_content {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column_content p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.column:first-child {
  display: block;
}

li {
  z-index: 1
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#categories {
  height: 100%;
}

#categories div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tabtext2 {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">

  <div class="column">
    <div class="column_content">
      <ul>
        <li id="one_link" class="tablink" data-target="categories">One</li>
        <li id="two_link" class="tablink" data-target="text_two">Two</li>
        <li id="three_link" class="tablink" data-target="text_three">Three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="texts">
    <div id="categories" class="column tabtext">
      <div class="column_content">
        <ul>
          <li id="cats_link" class="tablink2" data-target="cats_text">Cats</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="column tabtext2" id="cats_text">
        <div class="column_content">
          <p>The cat (Felis catus) is a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal. It is the only domesticated species in the family Felidae and is often referred to as the domestic cat to distinguish it from the wild members of the family.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column tabtext" id="text_two">
      <div class="column_content">
        <p>2 (two) is a number, numeral, and glyph. It is the natural number following 1 and preceding 3. It is the smallest and only even prime number. Because it forms the basis of a duality, it has religious and spiritual significance in many cultures.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column tabtext" id="text_three">
      <div class="column_content">
        <p>3 (three) is a number, numeral, and glyph. It is the natural number following 2 and preceding 4, and is the smallest odd prime number. It has religious or cultural significance in many societies.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that's genious! But it doesn't work if I try it with that ... Could you please show it as simple example?

Comment: Oh nice! Works pretty good! One last question: The text about cats doesn't fold in if I click for example »Two«, how is it possible to do that?

Comment: Done. Sorry, took longer than i expected :(

Comment: Ahhhhh thaaank you so much! <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3